# Id not getting removed from nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Hello I am trying to remove nested array object `id` from document but it is not getting removed. Although I am getting message `"Deleted"`

I have a response where the structure is :-

```
{
    "admins": {
        "users": [
            "5d0364048db4957100f33fea" //<===want to delete this relational id
        ],
        "email": "1cf1eede89@himail.online",
        "password": "$2a$10$vHyGxX9P.t0/ybKcmIzkc.ZCX18oHaVnvTgJIWA2gTNzJ3TCdXS4a",
    "_id": "5d0339d5b4b28b6ddff06802",
    "companyName": "GH",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I want to delete `users` `_id` from the array.

I tried this but it is not getting removed.

```
router.delete('/userDelete/:uId', checkAuth , (req, res, next) =>{
    if(req.userData.role2 === 'admin') {
        Admin.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.userId },{ $pull: { 'admins.users': req.params.uId}}) 
        .exec()
        .then(result => {
            res.status(200).send(["Deleted"]);
        })
        .catch(err =>{
        if (err.code == 500)
                    res.status(500).send(["Didn't get deleted"]);
        else
            return next(err);
        });
```

**Controller is like this :-**

```
var admin = new Admin();
    admin.companyName = req.body.companyName;
    admin.admins = {
                    email : req.body.email,
                    password: req.body.password,
                    users : [] 
    };
```

*I am stuck here , what changes I must do in my route ?*

**EDIT:- DB is like this** 
[image: DB]

Comment: console this `result`

Comment: @mehta-rohan getting null

Comment: that means your query to search the record is not working

Comment: i dont see any param `userId`. The only param i see is `uId`

Comment: @mehta-rohan yes, i got that , but I am unable to find the solution

Comment: @dimitristseggenes Yes, I need to query main object `_id`. I know I am doing something wrong. What changes should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here `Admin.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.userId }`

`req.params.userId` is **undefined**, because it does not exist in your path. `req.params` object holds only one property, `uId`.
 So your query does not find any data.
`req.params.userId` would have value if your method route had a form like this `router.delete('/userDelete/:userId/:uId)`.
So you could add userId in the url of your delete request and access it through `req.params` object. The new url should be like this

```
/userDelete/userId/uId
```

(e.g.)

```
userDelete/5d0339d5b4b28b6ddff06802/5d0364048db4957100f33fea
```

Comment: This is deleting my document.

Comment: No, it does not delete any document. Did you try it?

Comment: I updated my answer to help you understand better your problem. Change the url in your client side.

Comment: Yes i did the same .. its is deleting entire object

Comment: `console.log(req.params.userId)` and `console.log(req.params.uId)` and check the output if it is ok

Comment: got `undefined` on the first and `5d078f4f8f226624b26c0970` on the second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195065/discussion-between-dimitris-tseggenes-and-noobcoder).

Answer (score 0):

try to hard code your id here

```
Admin.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.userId },{ $pull: { 'admins.users': "5d0364048db4957100f33fea"}})
```

If it is working then do

```
req.params.uId.toString()
```

Comment: Didn't worked even after hard coded. Showing `"Deleted"` message but it is still there in the array

Comment: How will I query `{ _id: req.params.userId}` for the company , it is coming undefined. And also when I am consoling `result`, it is null

Comment: let me know hows is your user array looks like
it it contains only strings then it will work, but if id's are stored
in that way ObjectId("5ca5b052627cd94863a25b32")
then you should use this
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
{ _id: ObjectId (req.params.userId)}

Comment: Like this
db.getCollection('testing').update({_id:ObjectId("5d0765c44cacc6168afe7b42")},
{$pull:{"admins.users":"5ca5b0fa627cd94863a25b70"}}
)

Comment: then you should use ObjectId which is imported in the previous comments
Admin.update({ _id: ObjectId(req.params.userId) },{ $pull: { 'admins.users': ObjectId(req.params.uId)}})

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195063/discussion-between-syed-afzal-and-noobcoder).

Answer (score 0):

Try marking the '_id' as false in the schema itself for the array. For eg, in your schema, mark '_id' as false like below:

```
admin: {
  type: Object,
  users: [{
    _id: false
  }]
}
.
.
//rest of the schema
```

Comment: Why I should make it false ?

Comment: This would remove the _id from the nested array, and would return the result which you’re expecting.

Comment: Actually I am pushing only `_id` in the array. So if I make it false, nothing will get push. Remove from here I want  to delete in an operation. Thanks I didn't knew this. Now everything is working.

Comment: If this has resolved your issue, would you mind accepting and upvoting the answer?

Comment: I have already solved by dimitris tseggenes's  way. You solution will not push the `_id`. I need to push and delete. Thanks bdw.